# Changing bibliography style

Tags: biblatex

Sorry for another apparently very similar question on changing bibliography style.

In my document, before the main body, I have

```
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{Bibliography/Bibliography.bib}
```

Then, in the main body I have

```
\printbibliography[heading=bibintoc]
```

These commands will print my in-text citations in the numbered form. 
For example, in the bibliography.bib file, we can find

```
@article{Stuart10,
    author        = {A. M. Stuart},
    title         = {Inverse Problems: A Bayesian Perspective},
    journaltitle  = {Acta Numerica},
    year          = {2010},
    volume        = {19},
    pages         = {451-559}
}
```

And when in the main body I do `\cite{Stuart10}`, I get "[ 1 ]", when I would like to have something like "A.M.Stuart (2010)"

Comment: Add `style=authoryear` to the options of `biblatex` and use `\textcite{Stuart10}`.

Comment: @leandriis Are you saying to use \usepackage[backend=biber,style=authoryear]{biblatex}  ? I've tried this, but then my citation gets blacked out, and becomes just "Stuart10" instead of "[ 1 ]"

Comment: @leandriis I'm sorry, I changed my quick build, so that it would update the Bibliography. Thanks it worked. ;)